# how to get constants from a class excluding all constants that may have been descended from parents?

Tags: php, oop

here in second example PDO is populating MyClass with it's constants, how to filter them out ?

```
class MyClass {
  const PARAM_1 = 1;
  const PARAM_2 = 2;
  const PARAM_3 = 4;

  function MyMethod() {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    print_r($reflector->getConstants());
  }

}

$myInstance = new MyClass();
$myInstance->MyMethod();

//returns:
//Array
//(
//    [PARAM_1] => 1
//    [PARAM_2] => 2
//    [PARAM_3] => 4
//)

class MyClassPDO extends PDO {
  const PARAM_1 = 1;
  const PARAM_2 = 2;
  const PARAM_3 = 4;

  function MyMethod() {
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
    print_r($reflector->getConstants());
  }

}

$myInstancePDO = new MyClassPDO('sqlite::memory:');
$myInstancePDO->MyMethod();

//Array
//(
//    [PARAM_1] => 1
//    [PARAM_2] => 2
//    [PARAM_3] => 4
//    [PARAM_BOOL] => 5
//    [PARAM_NULL] => 0
//    [PARAM_INT] => 1
//    [PARAM_STR] => 2
//    [PARAM_LOB] => 3
//    [PARAM_STMT] => 4
//    [PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT] => -2147483648
//    [PARAM_EVT_ALLOC] => 0
//    [PARAM_EVT_FREE] => 1
//    [PARAM_EVT_EXEC_PRE] => 2
//....and so on
```

Comment: Just curious: Why?!? If you don't want constants there, don't put them there..

Comment: I'd guess he wants the constants of `MyClassPDO` without the inherited constants of `PDO`.

Comment: I want my constants but not these from parent PDO, these constants would still be in environment, but I want to know which are from child and wchich from parent class.

Comment: @user393087 use [ReflectionClass::getParentClass](http://php.net/manual/reflectionclass.getparentclass.php) to traverse the inheritance chain upwards and filter the out the constants defined in any parent.

Comment: have you tried getParentClass()->getConstants() and array_diff them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK

```
function MyMethod() {
  $reflector = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
  print_r(array_diff($reflector->getConstants(),$reflector->getParentClass()->getConstants()));
}
```

Comment: Should probably use `array_diff_assoc()` since you only want to exclude a value if it has the same key (name). But that would still hide overridden constants with the same name *and* value.