# How to convert php enum to array?

Tags: php, arrays, enums, spl

I've got the following enum:

```
abstract class DaysOfWeek
{
    const Sunday = 0;
    const Monday = 1;
    // etc.
}
```

How can I modify the following function to generate an array based on the `enum` above?

```
public function getOptions()
{
    return [
        0 => 'Sunday',
        1 => 'Monday',
    ];
}
```

Isn't it better to use `SplEnum` for this purpose?

Comment: you could use a builder function for populate the array ..

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's better to use Splenum, but I know this can be done using [ReflectionClass](http://php.net/ReflectionClass). Assuming you want getOptions to be defined in a class that extends DaysOfWeek, your code might look something like this:

```
abstract class DaysOfWeek
{
    const Sunday = 0;
    const Monday = 1;
    // etc.
}


class myClass extends DaysOfWeek {
    public function getOptions() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
            $constants = $oClass->getConstants();
            $retval = array();
            foreach($constants as $name => $val) {
                    $retval[$val] = $name;
            }
            return $retval;
    }
}

$o = new myClass();
var_dump($o->getOptions());
```

EDIT: here's an even more compact and efficient version of the getOptions function which uses native PHP functions:

```
    public function getOptions() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
            $constants = $oClass->getConstants();
            return(array_combine(array_values($constants), array_keys($constants)));
    }
```

EDIT 2: If getOptions is in a class that does NOT extend DaysOfWeek, you can simply refer to the classname like so:

```
class AnotherClass {
    public function getOptions() {
            $oClass = new ReflectionClass(DaysOfWeek);
            $constants = $oClass->getConstants();
            return(array_combine(array_values($constants), array_keys($constants)));
    }
}

$o = new AnotherClass();
var_dump($o->getOptions());
```

Comment: What if `getOptions` is not in a class that extends `DaysOfWeek`?

Comment: @Meysam You can just refer to DaysOfWeek instead of CLASS . I have edited my response to add another example.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Use of undefined constant DaysOfWeek - assumed 'DaysOfWeek'" on line 22

Comment: If I change it to `ReflectionClass("DaysOfWeek")`, I get this error: _"Class DaysOfWeek does not exist"_, but it exists and I can access its members.

Comment: Did you try it without the quotes. ReflectionClass(DaysOfWeek) ?

Comment: Yes as I said, I am getting this error without quotes: _"Use of undefined constant DaysOfWeek - assumed 'DaysOfWeek'"_

Comment: what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: php version 5.6.25

Comment: Aha...did you include/require the file that defines your DaysOfWeek class first? Before you can refer to a class in code, you have to include/require the file that defines it.

Comment: I tried to make sure the file has been correctly included, but still got the same error. I have to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: @Meysam Try it with quote sthen? Not sure what else to tell you. It works just fine on my machine when I run this php file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24154079/

Comment: Your `array_combine(array_values(), array_keys())` can be replaced by `array_flip()`....  e.g. `return array_flip($constants);`

Answer (score 1):

you can use: 
`$arr = array_column(DaysOfWeek::cases(), 'name');` 
it work for me 
if you want more details of how to use it follow this link 
[How to Get Values of All Backed Enum Cases as an Array in PHP?](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-get-values-of-all-backed-enum-cases-as-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SplEnum` if you like, but I find it hard to use. I prefer [Eloquent Enumeration](https://github.com/eloquent/enumeration) because it supports C++ style and Java style enums, complete with a range of methods to get values.

If you want to roll your own, you can use a `ReflectionClass` to inspect the constants, though be aware that if you have an inheritance tree that adds constants you'll have to be a [bit clever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597420/2908724). Otherwise, the answer from [S. Imp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679474/2908724) works well enough.